# AMPscript Returning a column value from a row only when it matches 2 other column values

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, lookup

I’d like to return a description column value when the values of 2 other columns in that row match the values I set earlier in the code with `set @value1 = “X”` and `set @value2 = “Y”`

For example:

```
set @model = "ABC"

set @offer_value = "XYZ"

set @offer = Lookup("OfferLookup","description","offer",@offer_value)
```

but then also make sure it matches the column model with the value I set for model.

So return the value in the column "description" only when the "offer" column has "XYZ" AND the "model" column has "ABC".

Is the Lookup function what I should be using for this type of value return, or is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with Lookup function:

```
set @model = "ABC"

set @offer_value = "XYZ"

set @offer = Lookup("OfferLookup","description","offer",@offer_value, "model", @model)
```

You can check the Lookup function syntax [here](https://ampscript.guide/lookup/).

> **Lookup(1,2,3,4,[5a,5b]...)**
>
> 5a: Additional column name that identifies the row to retrieve
>
> 5b: Additional value that identifies the row to retrieve
>
> NOTE: Additional pairs of columns and values can be appended as
> arguments.